# Quick way to make 26 macros (one for each letter)

Tags: latex

Instead of making a macro for each letter, as in

```
\def\bA{\mathbf{A}}
...
\def\bZ{\mathbf{Z}}
```

Is there a way to loop over a character class (like capital letters) and generate macros for each? I'd also like to do the same for Greek letters (using `bm` instead of `mathbf`).

Comment: By the way, I'm looking for a (La)Tex answer. Currently I have a bash script, but I want a (La)TeX only solution.

Comment: I don't know Latex, so I'll just add this as a comment - is there a scripting construct inside of whatever you're using to generate the macros? and if so, does it have the capability to call something to the effect of `echo -e -n '\x41'`. By incrementing the number '41' you'd go through all the ascii letters of the alphabet (starting with capital 'A').

Comment: @aronchick - That's the idea. Andrews's answer below does this (but in TeX we get to refer to alphabetic characters directly, avoiding ascii).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\def\mydefb#1{\expandafter\def\csname b#1\endcsname{\mathbf{#1}}}
\def\mydefallb#1{\ifx#1\mydefallb\else\mydefb#1\expandafter\mydefallb\fi}
\mydefallb ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\mydefallb
```

**New for Greek**

```
\def\mydefgreek#1{\expandafter\def\csname b#1\endcsname{\text{\boldmath$\mathbf{\csname #1\endcsname}$}}}
\def\mydefallgreek#1{\ifx\mydefallgreek#1\else\mydefgreek{#1}%
   \lowercase{\mydefgreek{#1}}\expandafter\mydefallgreek\fi}
\mydefallgreek {beta}{Gamma}{Delta}{epsilon}{etaex}{Theta}{Iota}{Lambda}{kappa}{mu}{nu}{Xi}{Pi}{rho}\mydefallgreek


$\bGamma\bDelta \bTheta \bLambda \bXi \bPi $

$\bbeta \bgamma\bdelta \bepsilon \betaex \btheta \biota \blambda \bkappa \bmu \bnu \bxi \bpi \brho$
```

Comment: This is great. So line 2 is essentially a loop because it inserts itself before the next character, right? Line one could be inserted into line 2, but is separate only for readability. A two line solution! The only down side is having to type the alphabet.

Comment: How about for a list of Greek letters? (`{Gamma}{mu}` or `\Gamma\mu` or some other reasonable list.)

Comment: I do not understand how you want to write Greek letters. You write `\bA, \bB`, etc for `A,B,...`. What is about Greek? `\bGamma`? `\bmmu` ? I do not understand.

Comment: Yes `\bGamma` or `\bmu` or `\bLambda` or `\blambda`. Currently I just have a list of these commands made manually.

Comment: `\text` for scripts: `2 ^ \bgamma` for example.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on Andrew's answer, here is a solution without `\expandafter`:

```
\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=\@ne
\def\@nameedef#1{\expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname}
\loop\ifnum\@tempcnta<27
  \@nameedef{b\@Alph\@tempcnta}{\noexpand\mathbb{\@Alph\@tempcnta}}
  \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
\repeat
```

This will define `\bA`, `\bB`, and so on, to expand to `\mathbb{A}`, `\mathbb{B}`, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't be better to define one command

```
\newcommand\bm[1]{\ensuremath{${\boldmath$#1$}}$}
```

and it can be used both in `text` mode and `math` mode.
Usage:

```
\[\bm{F(x)}=\int\bm\delta(x)\ dx]
\where \mb F is blah blah blah and \bm \delta is halb halb halb...
```

Result:
**F(x)**='inegral **delta**(x)'dx
Where **F** is blah blah blah and '**delta**' is halb halb halb...

Outer dollars are there to leave math (roman) mode because `\boldmath` command has no effect in math mode. Inner ones switch back to math (bold). Additional braces (`${\boldmath`) ensures that `\boldmath` command will work only with `#1`

Another advantage of this code is testing new commands for existence of `\bb` and `\bg`. So you can't crash LaTeX makros easily.

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: if you want to have macro specially designed for greek letters and another for latin letters you can add

`\newcommand\bl[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}`

into preamble and use it. - It will work only for latin letters.

Comment: +1 I guess my question is more academic than practical. Your suggestion is totally valid. I guess writing `\b X` instead of `\bX` isn't a very big distinction. Still, my original goal is to avoid the space. Your point regarding trashing existing macros is especially important. It would make very confusing code to redefine `\bf` for example.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend doing:

```
\newcommand{\b}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

as Crowley says, and similar for all the other alphabets.  However, if you *really* want to do it using LaTeX code, here's one that seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcounter{char}
\setcounter{char}{1}

\loop\ifnum\value{char}<27
\edef\c{\Alph{char}}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\csname\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter b\expandafter\c\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter\mathbb\expandafter{\c}}
\addtocounter{char}{1}
\repeat

\begin{document}

\(\bZ\)
\end{document}
```

I lost count of how many 'expandafter's there are in that!  To get lowercase letters, replace the Alph by alph.

Comment: Would it affect greek letters too? And why to use `\bH ello \bW orld`, when you can use `\b Hello \b World`?

Comment: +1 Cool solution. I never knew about `\expandafter` or `csname`. I think using the latter would allow you to trim your macro quite a bit.

Comment: @Crowley: I missed the bit about greek letters.  One could define a version of \alph and \Alph for greek letters.  Overkill for one application, but could be useful elsewhere.  With regard to your second point: I agree completely and I said so!  In my documents, I use (a variant of) your solution.  Nonetheless, the question of being able to loop over the alphabet was sufficiently intriguing that I thought I'd have a go.  I tried to strike a tone that showed that I wouldn't _actually_ do this in practice.  After all, 18 expandafters could be considered just a tab excessive!

Comment: @Andrew: no doubt you know this by now, but your bunch of \expandafter can be reduced a _lot_. `\expandafter\edef\csname b\Alph{char}\endcsname{\noexpand\mathbb{\Alph{char}}}` should do.